# why is RStudio server running my shiny app but the app is not showing up in shiny server on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I have my shiny app loaded and running on RStudio Server on my Amazon EC2 instance, but the Shiny Server still says that the app hasn't loaded.

[image]

I added the preserve_logs on; argument and copied and pasted my shiny app's server logs below:

```
[2021-10-01T21:40:48.734] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.16.958 (Node.js v12.20.0)
[2021-10-01T21:40:48.737] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2021-10-01T21:40:48.803] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2021-10-01T21:40:48.807] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
[2021-10-01T21:41:42.456] [INFO] shiny-server - Created bookmark state directory: /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks
[2021-10-01T21:41:42.457] [INFO] shiny-server - Created user bookmark state directory: /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny
[2021-10-01T21:41:43.252] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-01T21:41:43.271] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-01T21:46:44.173] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-01T21:46:44.197] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-01T22:39:02.890] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.16.958 (Node.js v12.20.0)
[2021-10-01T22:39:02.896] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2021-10-01T22:39:02.938] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.
[2021-10-01T22:39:02.943] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
[2021-10-01T22:56:56.389] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-01T22:56:56.390] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:21:45.959] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:21:45.982] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:22:51.708] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:22:51.715] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:33:44.028] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:33:44.048] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:46:47.422] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:46:47.430] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:46:58.048] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T00:46:58.092] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:15:38.458] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:15:38.464] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:17:41.391] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:17:41.394] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:19:43.084] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:19:43.090] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:25:00.885] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2021-10-02T02:25:00.891] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
```

And is here my shiny-server.conf file:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                       /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf                                                                 
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
preserve_logs true;
# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Why is the app running on RStudio Server but isn't loading to Shiny Server correctly?

Comment: According to a similar issue on Github (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/353), it could be related to some packages missing. Could you check your package dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for checking that! I actually did see that and I tested and ensured all necessary packages are loaded. The app runs in RStudio server, I can don't see that it's showing up in Shiny Server.

Comment: Is there a shiny server build compatible with your EC2 AMI? And, could you provide more details about your EC2 instance ? https://download3.rstudio.org/